# Multiple short if else condition

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, button, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement a multiple short if else condition in Javascript. I want to change the color of the ticket button based on its status:

`customer.status === "Solved" ? "success" : "warning"`

But i have 3 statuses for 1 ticket. I want to check the status of the request when is "Closed" and change the button of the ticket to "danger"

`customer.status === "Solved" && !== "Closed" ? "success" : "warning"` something like this, but it doesn't work. Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: Don't minify your developement code, let a minifier do it when transferring the code to the production.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for the various states and use a default property for having a state for non matching states.

```
const
    states = { Solved: 'success', Closed: 'danger', default: 'warning' },
    state = states[customer.status] || states.default;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was an idea too, but i wanted to add more conditions so i chose a helper function better

Answer (score 1):

I'd just refactor that into a helper function.

```
function getClassNameForCustomerStatus(customer) {
  if(customer.status === "Solved") {
    return "success";
  }
  if(customer.status !== "Closed") {
    return "success";
  }
  return "warning";
}
```

Comment: I used this method because i wanted to add more conditions so it's working now, thank you